# Can access webserver via IP but not Domain

Tags: apache2, dns, webserver

I've spent countless hours trying to figure this out via searching on the web and re-doing various configuration files from scratch and I've gotten to the point of giving up so I'm here.

I've installed the LAMP stack on my Ubuntu 16.04 server via VPS provided by SSDnodes. I've copied the 000-default.conf file and created my own copy titled example.com.conf. This was done in /etc/apache2/sites-available/

Then I used, `sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf` and then `sudo a2ensite example.com.conf` finally `sudo service apache2 reload`

I've also configured the DNS records from my DNS provider to point to the IP address of my server via A records as well, but no cigar. I can only access the site via IP Address thus far.

Running `apachectl -S` yields the below:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-
enabled/example.com.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

Here is my example.com.conf file under sites-available:

```
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public_html
```

The DNS records look like this:

```
Type: A 
Host: *.example.com
Answer: IP Address to server here
TTL: 300

Type: A 
Host: example.com
Answer: IP Address to server here
TTL: 300
```

Of course replace example.com with my actual domain name.

Comment: Are you sure that the DNS records are actually propagated, and that your domain actually points to the proper nameservers to *get* those DNS records?

Comment: It usually takes some time for it to reflect!

Comment: @ThomasWard Is there a command or way to check that they have actually propagated correctly? I did an nslookup and it does recognize that my domain points to the correct ip address.

Comment: @AlexPho do `nslookup YOURDOMAIN 8.8.8.8` which should query Google DNS - if it's there then you're good, if it's not then something bad is going on :P

Comment: @ThomasWard We're good! I'm still stumped on why the domain isn't working. Not sure if I'm missing any configurations on the server-side or the DNS provider side..

Answer (score 0):

I was doing some quick testing. I realized that my browser was automatically trying to connect via **HTTPS** and not via **HTTP**. This was causing my quick check trying to connect to my server running over HTTP (port 80) to fail since my browser was actually making request to HTTPS (port 443).

When I changed my request to use HTTP for the domain, my request went through.